# Comparing a string inside an object inside a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have two objects each containing a name/user variable. I want to compare these two strings inside the list to make sure no object from my calendar permissions list is also in my users list. The way i'm trying now is with two for loops and it seems to remove everything but one duplicate?

```
        calendarPermissions = new ObservableCollection<CalendarPermissions>(await parse.GetCalendarPermissionsAsync(user.Email));
        users = new ObservableCollection<UserList>(await parse.GetUserListAsync());

        for (int x = 0; x < users.Count; x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < calendarPermissions.Count; y++)
            {
                if (calendarPermissions[y].User == users[x].Navn)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{calendarPermissions[y].User} {users[x].Navn}");
                    users.Remove(users[x]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do they need to be in the observable collection before you engage in this looping process? It would seem that the extra indirection only makes the job harder ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking?
I would propose a solution like this to simplify your code:

```
var calenderPerms = new List<CalenderPerms>
{
     new CalenderPerms { User = "A" },
     new CalenderPerms { User = "B" },
     new CalenderPerms { User = "C" },
     new CalenderPerms { User = "D" },
};

var users = new List<User> 
{
    new User { Navn = "A" },
    new User { Navn = "B" },
    new User { Navn = "C" },
    new User { Navn = "F" },
};

// HashSet for faster .Contains query
var calenderPermsUsers = calenderPerms.Select(c => c.User).ToHashSet();
users.RemoveAll(u => calenderPermsUsers.Contains(u.Navn));
```

This removes all but User F from the users list, i.e. the intersection between the two lists - similarly to your own code.

Are you trying to obtain a different result?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var calendarPermissionUsers = calendarPermissions.Select(x => x.User).ToArray();
        users.RemoveAll(user => calendarPermissionUsers.Contains(user.Navn));
```